# Trying to call a member function pointer won't work

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I know member function pointers are a bit tricky, and I can call it if the function pointer isn't a member of the class itself, but can't seem to do it if it's a member of the class:

```
struct Window
{
    virtual void handleEvent() {};
    void (Window::*pHandleEvent)();
};

int main()
{
    Window w;
    void (Window::*fnptr)() = &Window::handleEvent;
    (w.*fnptr)(); // Works fine calling a local func ptr
    w.pHandleEvent(); // Calling its own member pointer doesn't work
    // Err: Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have
    // (pointer-to) function type
    (w.*pHandleEvent)();    // Doesn't work
    //Err: identifier "pHandleEvent" is undefined
    (w.*Window::pHandleEvent)();    // Doesn't work.
    // Err: A non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object.
}
```

Comment: I'd rather recommend you use a `std::function` variable and a lambda expression capturing `w` to accomplish that.

Comment: @TheDude Yes definitely std::function is awesome, but in this case I want to understand where the syntax is wrong, or if I can actually call it like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify two `Window` objects: the one whose pointer to use and the one on which to call the method.  If they’re the same, it’s

```
(w.*w.pHandleEvent)();
```

Note the precedence: if you instead have `A Window::*ptm;` and want a member of the `A` object, it’s `(w.*ptm).a_member`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was getting close with (w.*Window::pHandleEvent)();

Comment: @Zebrafish: You could do `(w.*&Window::handleEvent)()`, or even `(w.*(w.*&Window::pHandleEvent))()`, but that’s obviously pointless.

Comment: Gotta love C++ syntax sometimes

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 you can just rely on `std::invoke` for all your pointer to member needs:

```
std::invoke(w.pHandleEvent, w);
```

First argument is the pointer to member, the second is the object, or a pointer to it. And all the syntactical business is taken care of for you.